# how to add a graph to rexster sever (titan/cassamdra backend) and how to add a edges and verices to graph with python client?

Tags: python-2.7, cassandra, titan, rexster, bulbs

I have a rexster server 2.3.0 and titan-cassandra 0.3.0 .and one graph is configured with name of empgraph in rexster.xml file . How to add  edges and vertices's to that empgraph with titan client? All are installed in local host only .

Comment: unless you have a very specific reason you really should consider upgrading to the latest versions of Titan 0.5.4 (that would also mean using Rexster 2.5.0).

Comment: Then rexsterserver 2.3.0 and titan cassandra 0.3.0 will not work ?

Comment: i'm not saying that they don't work.  i'm saying that titan 0.5.4 brings many bug fixes and features that are likely important to a production implementation, so it would be better to use the newer version.